# Upstart node.js app on dokku deployment (Digital Ocean)

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, procfile, dokku

I deployed my node.js app to Digital Ocean, using [dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) (Docker powered mini-Heroku). The app is started by command in Procfile (`web: node app.js`).
How do I start it with [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), so that it restarts automatically after crashing?

Added:
I need it to be upstarted when I deploy with `git push dokku master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file `/etc/init/node.conf` and put the following code in.  Change `/opt/node_project/` to the path of your project.  You'll need to be root when editing this file so open your editor with `sudo`.

```
description "Node server"
author "eagor"


# Stanzas
#
# Stanzas control when and how a process is started and stopped
# See a list of stanzas here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn


script
  echo $$ > /var/run/node.pid;
  exec node /opt/node_project/app.js
end script


post-stop script
  rm -f /var/run/node.pid
end script
```

Now that you've created an Upstart config for your process you can start it from the command line:

```
$ sudo service node start
```

Upstart will monitor your process and will restart it any time it goes down.

It also redirects logs to `/var/log/upstart/node.log`.

### Forever

The above works directly with node and would bypass Dokku.  Seems like Upstart isn't the best way to handle this.

You should consider using the `forever` module.  Add `forever` to your package.json dependencies.  Then in your Procfile use this: `web: ./node_modules/forever/bin/forever app.js`

Comment: thank you. Can I have it started with Upstart when I deploy with 'git push'?

Comment: I think a better way to go for you would be the `forever` module.  I edited my answer.

Comment: I was considering it but read somewhere that upstart is more solid solution. Nevertheless, I used forever and it does just what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As of Dokku 0.7.0 it has restart policies built in:

https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/deployment/process-management.md#restart-policies

e.g.

```
# only restart it on Docker restart if it was not manually stopped
dokku ps:set-restart-policy node-js-app unless-stopped
```